# Android Image button with three states?

Tags: android

I want to have a image button with three possible states and depending on the logic display any one single image per state.

I could use a relative layout with three image buttons and toggle the visibility around.

But is there a way to define 3 states for an image button and toggle the images on a button level?

Thanks

Comment: selector tag in drawable

Answer (score 0):

use drawable selector [drawable](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html)